# ES6 syntax, harmony mode must be enabled with Uglifier.new(:harmony => true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, uglifier

I am facing this problem

`Uglifier::Error: Unexpected token: keyword (const). To use ES6 syntax, harmony mode must be enabled with Uglifier.new(:harmony => true).`

while deploying the project through capistrano on production.

I followed this solution

https://github.com/lautis/uglifier/issues/127#issuecomment-352224986

which suggests

replacing

`config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier`

with

`config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(harmony: true)`

but even after doing that I am still facing the same error. I dont understand what went wrong. I am using `uglifier (4.1.20)` version

Comment: Rails 6 is moving towards Webpack and away from Sprockets, so you may want to see if that approach works for you instead.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I'm having the same issue. And do have the harmony option set

Comment: This is very strange. Has anyone found a solution that does not involve getting rid of Uglifier?

Comment: We switched to the Terser gem, as per the recommendation and it worked well. We had to use `rails assets:clobber` and re-deploy to avoid a permissions issue in `tmp/cache/assets/sprockets`.

Answer (score 128):

Just leaving the answer here too:

In `config/environments/production.rb` replace

```
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
```

with

```
config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(harmony: true)
```

Answer (score 7):

[Uglifier](https://github.com/lautis/uglifier) only works with ES5. If you need to compress ES6, [ruby-terser](https://github.com/ahorek/terser-ruby) is a better option.

Comment: it's uglifier in ruby, not uglifyjs

Answer (score 7):

On Rails 6.1, I managed to solve this issue by:

1. Removing the `uglifier` gem from `Gemfile`.
2. Removing the `config.assets.js_compressor` entry in  `config/environments/production.rb` and `config/environments/development.rb`.

Ref.: https://www.mintbit.com/blog/rails-5-6-upgrade-es6-uglifier-bug

Comment: TY @Eduardo Sztokbant  I had to remove uglifier to fix this issue on my Rails 6.1.5 app.  It wasn't an issue until I added the TinyMCE Editor. Once I did that and tried to push to Heroku it coughed up a lung in that nasty error message you have posted here.  I tried the first solution it didn't work.  So I removed Uglifier all together.  Not only did it fix the issue but JavaScript is 5x faster now.  
Whatever the built in mechanism for the Asset pipeline with sprockets (I removed webpacker) seems to do a better job than Uglifier did.

Comment: Note: this is only a valid solution if you've upgraded your app to use Webpacker (the default asset compiler in Rails 6) instead of sprockets.

Comment: I'm using an older version of Rails (5.2.8) and deploying to Heroku and this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

**We get this issue to upgrade 5.2 to 6.1**

I fixed this issue to replace *uglifier* js_compressor with *terser*

`config/environments/production.rb` Replace

```
gem 'uglifier' # remove gem from Gemfile
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
or
config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(harmony: true)
```

to

```
gem 'terser' # add gem in Gemfile
config.assets.js_compressor = :terser
```